# stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to change this SQL query into eloquent laravel

```
SELECT vm.nik, ANY_VALUE(vm.nama_matakuliah), ANY_VALUE(vdhi.nidn), ANY_VALUE(vdhi.nama), ANY_VALUE(vdhi.jenjang_pendidikan_tertinggi), ANY_VALUE(vdhi.status), ANY_VALUE(vdhi.jabatan_fungsional), ANY_VALUE(vdhi.kd_homebase), ANY_VALUE(vdhi.jenjang_homebase), ANY_VALUE(vdhi.unit_homebase)
FROM vw_matakuliah vm
join vw_dosen_hcm_insani vdhi on vdhi.nik = vm.nik
where vm.nama_tahun_akademik = '2022/2023'
    and vdhi.status = 'Pegawai Tetap'
    and vm.kd_organisasi in (523, 917, 527)
GROUP BY vm.nik;
```

and i got this code

```
    $rekap = DB::table('vw_matakuliah as vm')
    ->select(DB::query('
        vm.nik,
        any_values(vhdi.nidn),
        any_values(vhdi.nama),
        any_values(vhdi.jenjang_pendidikan_tertinggi),
        any_values(vhdi.status),
        any_values(vhdi.jabatan_fungsional),
        any_values(vhdi.kd_homebase),
        any_values(vhdi.jenjang_homebase),
        any_values(vhdi.unit_homebase),
        any_values(vhdi.kd_homebase)')
    )->join('vw_dosen_hcm_insani as vhdi', 'vhdi.nik', 'vm.nik')
    ->where('vm.nama_tahun_akademik', $currentAcademicYears)
    ->whereIn('vm.kd_organisasi', $kdProdi)
    ->where('vhdi.status', 'Pegawai Tetap')
    ->groupBy('vm.nik')->get();
```

but i got an error:

> ErrorException: stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
> given in
> /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php:1145

but i'm pretty sure i don't use `stripos` function

Comment: Looks like you might be using Laravel 7. If so, know that it reached end of life in Sep 2020. You might want to upgrade your version of Laravel. The issue is coming up because eloquent is somehow calling Grammer.php (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php)'s wrap() method. That has stripos() PHP function on line 1145. Its $value argument should be a string but Laravel is sending an object.

Comment: @zedfoxus what if i can't upgrade my version? should i change my eloquent?

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace showing who called Grammer.php and who called that file and so on? If you can generate a stacktrace, perhaps someone might be able to point out what you could do. If you can't generate a stracktrace or point out where the issue originates, you might want to you use SQL instead of eloquent until you find out what's throwing off Grammar.php